# Where can I find free WPF controls and control templates?

Tags: wpf, controls, templates

I am looking for some recommendations on good places to find libraries of controls/templates/styles for WPF. I know about the usual places like Infragistics, but it seems to me that there should be some kind of community effort by now to share nice, clean, well written controls for WPF controls.

I am not big on the design side, and it would be nice to fill out my personal libraries with some nice examples from people who are better at design.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: I agree ... great question. I would totally expect some community driven site where we could browse and download some nice looking skins for the standard WPF controls.

Comment: Yup, like WordPress themes. May the wish come true soon.

Comment: Similar: [Free WPF themes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes)

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=wpf%20control

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 12):

I strongly recommend the [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/) it's simply awesome!

Answer (score 9):

Syncfusion has a free community version available with over 650 controls.

[Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense)

You will find an FAQ there with any licensing questions you may have, it sound great to be honest. Have fun!

Edit: The WPF controls themselves are 100+, the number of 650+ refers to all controls for all areas (WPF, Windows Forms etc).

Comment: Seems their "Free" community license is more of a click bait than a real thing

Answer (score 5):

I searched for some good themes across internet and found nothing. So I ported selected controls of GTK Hybrid theme. It's MIT licensed and you can find it here:

https://github.com/stil/candyshop

It's not enterprise grade style and probably has some flaws, but I use it in my personal projects.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

They have one for free as a sample at http://www.xamltemplates.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Silverlight and WPF Dashboards and gauges](http://dashboarding.codeplex.com)

Simple (but great) piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

Codeplex is definitively the right place.
Recent "post": [SofaWPF.codeplex.com](http://sofawpf.codeplex.com/) based on [AvalonDock.codeplex.com](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/), an IDE like framework.

Comment: sofawpf.codeplex.com not found.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Reuxables](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx) although it comes at a cost.

Comment: Just found this post and saw that Reuxables has a set of free themes available  now.