# Any free WPF themes?

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm not a designer, so I'm looking for some free WPF themes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The top answers are seriously dated, check out the WPF project on CodePlex first.

Comment: The good ones aren't free.

Comment: Similar: [Free WPF controls and control templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121724/where-can-i-find-free-wpf-controls-and-control-templates)

Comment: This link might help you http://www.nukeation.com/free.aspx

Comment: Just released: http://brianlagunas.com/free-metro-light-and-dark-themes-for-wpf-and-silverlight-microsoft-controls/ Metro themes for both WPF and Silverlight

Comment: http://materialdesigninxaml.net

Comment: [ModernWPF UI Library](https://github.com/ghost1372/ModernWpf) has a VS VSIX extension.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The only one that I have found (for sale) is [reuxables](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx). A little pricey, if you ask me, but you do get 9 themes/61 variations.

#### UPDATE 1:

A WPF Contrib project ... which does have 1 [theme](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfcontrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Themes&referringTitle=Home) that they never released.

#### UPDATE 2:

Rudi Grobler (above) just created CodePlex [community](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfthemes) for this ... starting with converted themes he mentions above. See his blog [post](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2008/11/06/wpf-themes-released.aspx) for more info. Way to go Rudi!

#### UPDATE 3:

As another answer below has mentioned, since this question and my answer were written, the WPF Toolkit has incorporated some free [themes](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home), in particular, the themes from the Silverlight Toolkit. Rudi's [project](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) goes a little further and adds several more ... but depending on your situation, the WPF Toolkit might be all you need (and you might be installing it already).

Comment: The link to Reuxables themes by Nukeation is broken. At current time of writing http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx will get you to the correct location.

Comment: Highrobotics created free theme at http://highrobotics.com/we-did-it/wpf-themes.aspx

Answer (score 16):

Not purely themes, but [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) provides Windows 8 Look and feel with a few variants like dark and light base themes with green,blue etc for text and others. Its pretty cool and can be used out of the box.

Comment: Oops. sorry its already mentioned by Legoless. Didn't noticed.

Answer (score 12):

I bought a theme from [www.xamltemplates.net](http://www.xamltemplates.net). The themes ship with source code so you can tweak them. They also offer a free theme (source code included).

Comment: I find it worrying that many of the posts in this thread look a lot like plain advertisements.

Comment: Which posts exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 12):

I also found those:
http://xceed.com/ProThemes_WPF_Features.html

And of course there are many implementations of Metro UI for WPF:
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro
http://mosaicproject.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11):

There are some **Microsoft Themes** in the WPF page on CodePlex:

[CodePlex - Windows Presentation Foundation](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf)

Answer (score 7):

Read [this](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2008/10/29/silverlight-love-for-wpf.aspx) article on how to convert a silverlight theme to WPF... The have a look at the [Silverlight toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight), thy released loads of free silverlight themes!!!

- Expression Dark
- Expression Light
- Rainier Purple
- Rainier Orange
- Shiny Blue
- Shiny Red

Answer (score 7):

The direct link to the WPF themes project is here: [WPF themes](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfthemes)

Download the source code (currently there is no binary release) and check out the demo that comes with it to get an idea of the capabilities.

You will need to install the [WPF toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx) in order to compile and use the themes.

This is an ongoing project, so I think more themes will be added in the future. It will probably ruin the the sites trying to sell themes to you, but it is great for one man shops that can't invest too much up front.

Answer (score 6):

You can download 7 free WPF themes from http://www.nukeation.com/free.aspx . I found them very useful. You should surely try it out. They are designed by the people who have desiged the official WPF & Silverlight Themes.

Comment: These free themes do not include DataGrid support nor a few other new controls added in .NET 4 (per their download page).

Answer (score 4):

Here's [another one](https://web.archive.org/web/20100220104356/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/dave/archive/2008/10/06/dave-s-glossy-controls-for-silverlight-2-released.aspx) for Silverlight. And a list of [nice gradients](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805231952/http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2008/10/21/more-xaml-gradients.aspx) to use.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/expression-clone)'s my expression dark theme for WPF controls.

Comment: Final link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

[Sunny Orange WPF Theme](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/03/sunny-orange-wpf-theme-1.html)

Comment: Final link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

[Amazings WPF Controls](http://amazingwpfcontrols.codeplex.com/) includes the Jetpack theme for WPF.

Comment: Jetpack is by far the prettiest theme I found so far!

Answer (score 2):

We use the Assergs Application Framework themes:

http://www.codeplex.com/appfx

They have a nice office look and feel to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try www.reuxables.com - we have both commercial and free themes, and it is the largest and most diverse theme library for WPF.

Comment: @Sarah- free themes- http://www.nukeation.com/free.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Viblend [WPF themes](http://www.viblend.com/Products/NET/WPF/Controls/WPFProducts.aspx) are free.

Comment: The last update of this project has been done in 2010. Also it doesn't include DataGrid sytles.