# Need themes for the WPF Toolkit controls (especially the DataGrid)

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, wpftoolkit

I just downloaded the nice themes collection from the [Codeplex WPF Themes site](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes). I like the WhisterBlue and BureauBlue themes a lot, but neither contain any styles for the new controls included in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) (`DataGrid`, `DatePicker`, and `Calendar`).

It seems like *someone* out there must have extended the themes to cover these controls, but I've had no luck finding them. So, if you have any leads, I'd love to hear them.

I should also mention that I've been trying to port a Silverlight version of the BureauBlue `DataGrid` theme to WPF (see: [How do you port a theme from Silverlight to WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611135/how-do-you-port-a-theme-from-silverlight-to-wpf)), but that has been quite unsuccessful so far.

Comment: A good (much needed) WPF DataGrid theme : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736530/wpf-datagrid-style-silverlight-datagrid/4269855#4269855

Comment: Please vote [here](http://goo.gl/QDYxY) and [here](http://goo.gl/S8ekJ) and leave rude comments!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1736530/75500

Answer (score 7):

WPFreakyStyley has extended all of its themes to the WPF Toolkit.  You might be able to find one that matches the CodePlex theme you're using.
[WPFreakyStyley](http://www.WPFreakyStyley.com)

Answer (score 0):

The WhistlerBlue theme is included in the Silverlight toolkit [Oct 2009](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home) in the preview band.

Comment: @Phillip, thanks. That's got a lot more in it than the WPF Toolkit. I'm having a little trouble with the namespaces and assembly references, though. I can't seem to find matching assemblies for the examples on the Silverlight Toolit Samples page (http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html).

Comment: I should mention, I downloaded and installed the toolkit (October 2009) but if I try to add a reference for `System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit`, I can't find it in the list. Is this because I'm using Visual Studio 2008? Is it because my project is WPF, not Silverlight?

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question and pointed you to something that related only to SL. And yes, you can't the reference because you are using WPF and the assembly is SL.

Comment: Ahh, well I had a Silverlight tag for my question (just removed it), so it was actually my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Actipro Software has a free, opensource project on CodePlex called the "[WPF Control Contrib](http://actipro.codeplex.com/)". It contains code that extends the functionality of the built-in DataGrid and includes five themes for the DataGrid: AeroNormal, Classic, LunaHomestead, LunaMetallic and LunaNormal

Answer (score 0):

High Robotics has [free WPF theme](http://highrobotics.com/we-did-it/wpf-themes.aspx) that can be applied to apps and does not have dolly glossy style.

But it requires at least WPF.NET 4 (WPF Toolkit was included in that version).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes) is discussion about free wpf themes (MahApps.Metro, nukeaction and others).