# Where can I find free WPF Datagrid Styles?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Where can I find free WPF Datagrid Styles?

Comment: Can't help you with anything good unless you tell me your budget is more than 0$.

Comment: hmmmm.. Budget doesn't matter. I want a great solution which you people are comfortable with. If any free solution is there that will be greatly appreciated so that i can modify it. Thnx

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736530/wpf-datagrid-style-silverlight-datagrid/4731626#4731626

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603179/need-themes-for-the-wpf-toolkit-controls-espeically-datagrid

Answer (score 3):

check out code plex http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/

Comment: it was asked in way back 2010 and now there are lot of sample there including your sample

Answer (score 2):

[reuxables](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx) have a free theme and have just included datagrids in their styles. No I don't work there. Bought one of their themes though, and it's great :D

Comment: Looks like their free Mercury style does datagrids but only the .NET 4 version

Comment: @codeulike I downloaded Mercury from http://www.nukeation.com/free.aspx but datagrids are not styled.. Can you please tell me how you got the theme to style datagrids? My application is running .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, (on december 2010) it seems there is no free themes for datagrid.

According to the links there is free wpf themes, 
there are paid themes for datagrid.  But there is no *free* datagrid themes.