# Is there something like Wordpress Themes for WPF, like off the shelf basic designs?

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm no designer and can't get a custom design done. I would love it if there were basic but attractive free or cheap WPF designs available much like the wide-spread Wordpress Themes.

Any URLs out there?

Thanks!

Gregg

PS [A nice WPF Design by Felix Corke on Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/default.aspx?month=2008-07)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [wpf themes page at codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/wpfthemes) or even better : [this thread at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes)