# Theme similar to Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio Test 2010 Professional

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

Anyone can let me know where to find theme Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio Test 2010 Professional; I would really appreciate. I want to develop application with that Theme.

Thanks
Ocean

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [Any free WPF themes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes)

I've looked for the same thing earlier and 
[Reuxables Theme, **Developer**](http://www.nukeation.com/themes.aspx#2) looks pretty similar to Visual Studio 2010. It's not free though but they do have 7 free themes so have a look there.

Here is a screenshot from their site
[image]

---

Although it is not the Visual Studio 2010 theme, here are some more free themes with Office 2010.
[WPF Office 2010 Blue Theme(Free)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3947f3a9-054c-4637-9070-68aadbb1e8b1/)

Hopefully some of these links can help you out and if you do find Visual Studio 2010 Theme (especially for free) than be sure to update here