# Where can i find Free WPF controls

Tags: wpf, gridview, controls

Is there any site available where I can find free WPF controls like Griview ? I am currently working on a complex project where I need a customizable WPF Gridview like telerik

Answer (score 2):

You can use controls from the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) as well as [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

On [codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com) and [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com). However the best always cost money.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the controls in AvalonControlsLibrary on code plex, it is having a DataGridView control apart from other controls. -

http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home&ProjectName=avaloncontrolslib

DataGridView

DataGridView is a maybe a misleading name for this control. This control is far from being the same as the WinForms DataGridView (maybe someday it will J). Basically this control is a WPF ListView control but it is capable of auto generate the GridViewColumns for you. It generates the columns by looking at the objects’ properties. You can also specify how you generate the columns by decorating your properties with a custom attribute. For more information have a look at this post. http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/01/listview-with-auto-generation-of-column-enable-disable-columns/

Similar SF question - [Where can I find free WPF controls and control templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121724/where-can-i-find-free-wpf-controls-and-control-templates)